# get all a href attribute list of given url in php

Tags: php, dom

I want to display all link in given url. I found it by searching. but it also showing the attribute of `"title"` of `"a"` tag. I want only attribute of "href"

```
<?php 
$link = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($link);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');


foreach ($links as $link){

     echo $link->nodeValue;
echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include a little bit of the HTML code of the page you are going through

Answer (score 1):

The value of `<a>value</a>` is echoed with `echo $link->nodeValue;` remove that code and you resolved the issue.

However, internal links of the website are not really handled here.
Perhaps add something like this:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';

... # other code.

foreach($links as $link){
    if($link[0] == '/'){ #link is a string, [0] refers to the first character.
        echo $url, $link->getAttribute('href');
    } else {
        echo $link->getAttribute('href'), "\n";
    }
}
```

One other thing, suppressing errors (`@`)is not the way to go. Find another resolution that works without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a combination of the Symfony2 framework and Goutte.

Symfony2: https://symfony.com/

Goutte: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

You'd make a new instance:

```
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();
```

Then request the page:

```
// Go to the symfony.com website
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.symfony.com/blog/');
```

Then try to get what you need:

```
$links = $crawler->filter('a[href]');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo '<a href="$link">$link</a><br>';
}
```